# How to convert below function to C#

Tags: vb.net-to-c#

How can the method below be converted to C#?

```
private int GetTotalNumberLines()
{
    // be safe about the array
    int size = 0;
    if (mLines == null) {
       size = -1;
    } 
    else {
       size = Information.UBound(mLines);
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: As new user always good to visit: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you can get the size of an array with `Length`:

```
size = mLines.Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no info in the question of what mLines is, but since the comment states `// be safe about the array`, I guess it's an array:

The only thin you need to change is the method `UBound`, which in C# is a property on the array called `Length`.

The entire code would look like this:

```
private int GetTotalNumberLines()
{
   // be safe about the array
   int size = 0;
   if (mLines == null) {
      size = -1;
   } 
   else {
      size = mLines.Length;
   }
   return size;
}
```